# OpenCV rectangle draw function

Tags: algorithm, opencv, colors, computer-vision

OpenCV facilitates drawing [rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) provided the top-left corner and bottom-right corner of rectangle. I wanted to know which algorithm is uses to draw the rectangle, for example, all polygon filling algorithms that I know of, fills the entire polygon, i.e. [boundary fill algorithm](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/outprims/polygn6a.htm) etc. 
 I didn't find any color filling algorithm that fills only the boundary. Please, write if I missed something or if there is such algorithm.

Comment: A rectangle is nothing but just a group of 4 straight lines which are successively perpendicular to each other, So drawing a rectangle can be thought of as drawing 4 line segments. I am not sure how OpenCV has implemented it internally, but this line approach makes sense

Comment: From the two given points we can easily find the four vertices of a rectangle. So we can easily draw line segments using them.

Comment: That is right @Zdar... But what I wanted to ask is how does openCV fundamentally do it... As I wanted to find out and didn't get anything on internet. Please mention source also.

Comment: Yes @krishna... That's how it CAN be done, that's the basic concept but how OpenCV does it that was my prime concern, as I was looking through some color filling algos and none seem to work this way. There are approaches too like to consider a line as a thin rectangle and use polygon fill algos... But how exactly does OpneCV implements it?

Answer (score 2):

from [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L1843):

```
void rectangle( InputOutputArray _img, Point pt1, Point pt2,
                const Scalar& color, int thickness,
                int lineType, int shift )
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()
Mat img = _img.getMat();

if( lineType == CV_AA && img.depth() != CV_8U )
    lineType = 8;

CV_Assert( thickness <= MAX_THICKNESS );
CV_Assert( 0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT );

double buf[4];
scalarToRawData(color, buf, img.type(), 0);

Point2l pt[4];

pt[0] = pt1;
pt[1].x = pt2.x;
pt[1].y = pt1.y;
pt[2] = pt2;
pt[3].x = pt1.x;
pt[3].y = pt2.y;

if( thickness >= 0 )
    PolyLine( img, pt, 4, true, buf, thickness, lineType, shift );
else
    FillConvexPoly( img, pt, 4, buf, lineType, shift );
}
```

here,we can see that if thickness is passed it draws rectangle using `PolyLine`.